# Creating a BinarySortTree method that returns items in a sorted fashion

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```
def items(self) -> List:
    """Return all of the items in the BST in sorted order.

    >>> BinarySearchTree(None).items()  # An empty BST
    []
    >>> bst = BinarySearchTree(7)
    >>> left = BinarySearchTree(3)
    >>> left._left = BinarySearchTree(2)
    >>> left._right = BinarySearchTree(5)
    >>> right = BinarySearchTree(11)
    >>> right._left = BinarySearchTree(9)
    >>> right._right = BinarySearchTree(13)
    >>> bst._left = left
    >>> bst._right = right
    >>> bst.items()
    [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
    """
    if self.is_empty():
        return []
    elif self._root:
        lst = [self._root]
        if self._left != BinarySearchTree(None):
            lst.insert(lst.index(self._root) - 1, self._left._root)
            self._left.items()
        if self._right != BinarySearchTree(None):
            lst.insert(lst.index(self._root) + 1, self._right._root)
            self._right.items()

    return lst
```

What's wrong with my code? I'm trying recursion and it manages to half-pass the docstring example and returns [3, 7, 11]. I can't seem to implement the actual *recursion* part of the code, so that it returns more.

Note: I'm trying to complete this method *without dumping the numbers and then sorting the list*.

Comment: You don't use the result when you recurse with `self._{left,right}.items()` and you don't pass the `lst` object to the recursion either, so each step of the recursion creates its own `lst` and ends up effectively not doing anything. I think you need something like `child_items = self._left.items()` and then append them to `lst` too and I think you don't need the line where you append `self._left.root` because that root should be returned by the recursion.

Comment: `BinarySearchTree` is not defined.

Comment: @ScottHunter what is the point of your comment? `items()` is clearly the definition of a method on that class, he just didn't include the rest of the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that BinarySearchTree is defined as the owner of the whole tree and that its root property is a proper TreeNode with a left and right hierarchy of TreeNodes (i.e. not another BinarySearchTree, which wouldn't make any sense),

You could  make that a recursive generator:

```
def items(self):
    def DFS(node):
        if node.left: yield from DFS(node.left)   # all smaller nodes
        yield node                                # this node
        if node.right: yield from DFS(node.right) # all larger nodes
    return [] if self.is_empty() else list(DFS(self.root))
```